# Dax get the single rank result from rankx measurement

Tags: powerbi, dax

How can i get the single result from rankx measurement, for example I need the result for "Test3" which is in this case 3.

```
DAX formula for rank: =
RANKX(
   ALLSELECTED(CompetitionComp);
   CALCULATE(
       SUM(CompetitionComp[Base price WS])
   )
)
```

Results:

```
Name    Ranking
test1  | 1
test2  | 2
test3  | 3
test4  | 4
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is what you want:

```
DAX formula for rank 3: =
VAR _rank_3 = RANKX(
   ALLSELECTED(CompetitionComp);
   CALCULATE(
       SUM(CompetitionComp[Base price WS])
   )
)

RETURN IF(_rank_3 = 3, SUM(CompetitionComp[Base price WS]) )
```